Bootstrap 5 selectpicker change background-color
The standard in our place is that every input field should be set to color lightgoldenyellow.
I cannot set the background-color of selectpicker in Bootstrap 5.
This is my code:
I have also attached the bootstrap/jquery that I have used.


<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" >
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.5.2/css/all.min.css"/>

<!--jQuery-->
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.4/css/all.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<!-- Bootstrap 5 Font Icon CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-icons@1.11.3/font/bootstrap-icons.min.css">

<!--Icon Scout-->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unicons.iconscout.com/release/v4.0.8/css/line.css">

<!--Bootstrap/jQuery Select picker-->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.14.0-beta2/css/bootstrap-select.min.css"/>

<!--<link rel="stylesheet" href="home_test.css">-->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="home.css">

<!--scripts -->
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.7.1.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.13.2/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.14.0-beta2/js/bootstrap-select.min.js"></script>


<div class="container" style="overflow:visible;">
        <select name="instructor_a" id="" style="background-color: lightgoldenyellow;"  class="selectpicker" data-live-search = "true" data-size="3" title="講師選択">
        <?php
            $query_instructor = "SELECT name_ FROM users
            where userlevel = '2'";

            $stmt_instructor = $pdo->prepare($query_instructor);
            //$stmt_interviewee->bindParam(":training_id", $training_id);
            $stmt_instructor->execute();

            $result_query_instructor = $stmt_instructor->fetchAll();

            foreach ($result_query_instructor as $instructors) {
                echo "<option value ='$instructors[name_]'";
                if($instructor_a === $instructors["name_"]) {
                    echo "selected";
                }
                echo">$instructors[name_]</option>";
            }

        ?>
        </select>
</div>



I have tried adding in-line style: style="background-color:lightgoldenyellow;" but no luck.
I have also tried adding a class in selectpicker such as class ="instructor-select",
Then in my css file I included ".instructor-select {background-color:lightgoldenyellow; }" still no luck.
How should I override the bootstrap selectpicker style?

did you try to use lightgoldenrodyellow instead? the color value you are using is not valid


Use a valid color name 2) Provide a [mcve] that allows to reproduce the issue (read minimal and reproducible - we don't want 10+ different and unrelated CSS and JS libraries + some PHP code in the middle) 3) You tagged your question with [tag:bootstrap-5] but the bootstrap-select library is for Bootstrap 4?


@DiegoD I have tried "lightgoldenrodyellow" in-line style and it still not working. I also tried it in css, still not working.

@newbiecoder I had an answer that I deleted because it seemed to be redundant... anyway since you replied saying that you couldn't apply the suggestion given, I undeleted the whole answer having a working demo inside

@MrUpsidown Simply because there is no bootstrap-select library for Bootstrap 5. I did include the other libraries because it might be causing the issue. And for your information, even though the library is for Bootstrap 4, it is somehow supported in Bootstrap 5 but it was stopped. The functionality works well, its just I want to standardize the color.

@DiegoD Still, thanks for the suggestion.

@newbiecoder what did you mean by still? do you "still" have problems? did you try the live snippet? what's wrong? can you add a comment under the specific answer addressing the problem so I can better understand?

@DiegoD I saw your answer now. IT works perfectly!! Thank you so much! Life saver! I'm sorry I could not upvote your answer, not enough reputation, but it was saved.

@newbiecoder for the sake of records I took the chance to further style added details... it's everything explained in the single css rule used having 6 different selectors

Thank you so much. It helped a lot. Based from the 6 different selectors you have added, I am also trying to change the color into "background-color: gray" when it is disabled. I have tried several codes such as : .bootstrap-select > .dropdown-toggle.bs-placeholder:disabled {
background-color: gray !important; }          Anyway, I will try to put it on another question when it is available after 4 days. Thanks you so much @DiegoD

@newbiecoder what do you mean by disabled? if you disable the <select> adding the attribute disabled in the html tag, the whole control will be styled as gray and having a cursordisallowing any further interaction with the dropdown. I improved my answer adding a disabled dd as reference

I guess your main problem was having used the wrong identifier for the color you wished to address. A valid color name close to what you used is actually lightgoldenrodyellow.
Now having fixed that, what you need to style are:

.bootstrap-select .dropdown-toggle - dropdown box
.bootstrap-select > .dropdown-menu li a - all dropdown options
.bootstrap-select > .dropdown-toggle:focus - dropdown :focus
.bootstrap-select > .dropdown-toggle:hover - dropdown :hover
.bootstrap-select > .dropdown-menu li.active a - dropdown value
.bootstrap-select > .dropdown-menu li a:active - option selected among many

Plus it's worth nothing that, with no further stylings, when the <select> has the disabled attribute, the dropdown gets styled with a gray background and a a cursor disallowing any further interaction.
Here's a full example (including a disabled dropdown):


.bootstrap-select > .dropdown-toggle, /* dropdown box */
.bootstrap-select > .dropdown-menu li a, /* all dropdown options */
.bootstrap-select > .dropdown-toggle:focus, /* dropdown :focus */
.bootstrap-select > .dropdown-toggle:hover /* dropdown :hover */
{
  background-color: lightgoldenrodyellow;
}

/* dropdown - option selected - shown as the value of the dropdown */
.bootstrap-select > .dropdown-menu li.active a{  
  font-weight: bold;
  color: black;
}

/* dropdown - option selected - shown among the other available options */
.bootstrap-select > .dropdown-menu li a:active {
  color: red;
}
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.5.2/css/all.min.css" />

<!--jQuery-->
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.4/css/all.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<!-- Bootstrap 5 Font Icon CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-icons@1.11.3/font/bootstrap-icons.min.css">

<!--Icon Scout-->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unicons.iconscout.com/release/v4.0.8/css/line.css">

<!--Bootstrap/jQuery Select picker-->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.14.0-beta2/css/bootstrap-select.min.css" />

<!--<link rel="stylesheet" href="home_test.css">-->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="home.css">

<!--scripts -->
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.7.1.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.13.2/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.14.0-beta2/js/bootstrap-select.min.js"></script>

<br>

<div class="container" style="overflow:visible;">
  <select
    name="instructor_a"
    id=""
    class="selectpicker"
    data-live-search="true"
    data-size="3"
    title="講師選択"    
    >
    <option value="1">bogus1</option>
    <option value="2">bogus2</option>
    <option value="3">bogus3</option>
  </select>
</div>

<hr>

<div class="container" style="overflow:visible;">
  <select
    name="instructor_b"
    id=""
    class="selectpicker"
    data-live-search="true"
    data-size="3"
    title="講師選択 - (disabled)"    
    disabled
    >
    <option value="1">bogus1</option>
    <option value="2">bogus2</option>
    <option value="3">bogus3</option>
  </select>
</div>

<hr>




I improved the answer by: using better focused selectors; explaining correctly what each selector does; including a demo of a disabled dropdown

Use the bootstrap class form-select and override it with your desire color


.form-select ,
.form-select:focus,
.form-select:active,
.form-select.show {
    background-color:  #FFC000 !important;
}
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<select class="form-select" aria-label="Default select example">
  <option selected>Open this select menu</option>
  <option value="1">One</option>
  <option value="2">Two</option>
  <option value="3">Three</option>
</select>




Use the CSS selector .bootstrap-select > .dropdown-toggle and set the background on that. So in your case, it would be:
.bootstrap-select > .dropdown-toggle {
  background-color: lightgoldenyellow;
}

Though, as Diego D mentioned, lightgoldenyellow is not a valid color, so that could also cause you issues.

This is also correct and same as Diego D's answer, but "!important" should be added.
